# Como delimitar a área do ".animate()" do jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Gostaria de mover o boneco e ele ficar apenas dentro da div, quando batesse na linha que delimita o quadrado, ele parasse e não conseguisse ir alem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).keydown(function(x){
            if(x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39){               
                 $('.pacman')
                    .animate({left: '1180px'}, 'slow')
                    .css({ transform : 'rotate(360deg)'});               
            }

            if(x.which == 40 || x.keyCode == 40){               
                 $('.pacman')
                    .animate({top: '1180px'}, 'slow')
                    .css({ transform : 'rotate(90deg)'});   
            }

            if(x.which == 37 || x.keyCode == 37){               
                 $('.pacman')
                    .animate({left: '-1180px'}, 'slow')
                    .css({ transform : 'rotate(180deg)'});  
            }

            if(x.which == 38 || x.keyCode == 38){               
                 $('.pacman')
                    .animate({top: '-1180px'}, 'slow')
                    .css({ transform : 'rotate(270deg)'});  
            }


          }).keyup(function(){
            $('.pacman').stop();
          });
        });
```

```css
.pacman{
  position:absolute;
}       
.cenario{
  border:5px solid black;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin-left:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cenario">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWuBaJWq9UP_ILy5Tgz5-5Z6dMm8f7URRSh8Pr2pMU0LZfvPEG" class="pacman" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Tem como você colocar uma demo no JSFIDDLE? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Fala Samir Braga,cara, nao sei usar esse JSFIDDLE, nem conhecia. Mas é simples de entender, eu movo o boneco com as setas do teclado, mas gostaria que ele ficasse apenas dentro desse quadrado(div), mas se tu rodar o programa pode perceber que ele(o boneco) ta saindo pra fora do quadrado. Queria delimitar a area que ele pode ir, nesse caso apenas dentro da div. Nao sei se deu pra entender...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha sugestão levando em consideração seu método atual de mover o boneco:

Dê um `position: relative` na `div.cenario`:

```
.cenario {
  /* ... */
  position: relative;
}
```

Assim, como a boneco tem um `position: absolute`, este se delimitará automaticamente dentro da caixa.

Assim, basta armazenar os tamanhos dos dois elementos principais em variáveis:

```
var PM_width = $('.pacman').width();
var PM_height = $('.pacman').height();
var Cenario_width = $('.cenario').width();
var Cenario_height = $('.cenario').height();
```

- O máximo para a direita será:

  ```
  Cenario_width - PM_width
  ```
- O máximo para a esquerda será `0`
- O máximo para baixo será:

  ```
  Cenario_height - PM_height
  ```
- O máximo para cima também será 0

### Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(x) {
   x.preventDefault()
    var PM_width = $('.pacman').width();
    var PM_height = $('.pacman').height();
    var Cenario_width = $('.cenario').width();
    var Cenario_height = $('.cenario').height();

    if (x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39) {
      $('.pacman')
        .animate({
          left: Cenario_width - PM_width + "px"
        }, 'slow', 'linear')
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(360deg)'
        });
    }

    if (x.which == 40 || x.keyCode == 40) {
      $('.pacman')
        .animate({
          top: Cenario_height - PM_height + "px"
        }, 'slow', 'linear')
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
        });
    }

    if (x.which == 37 || x.keyCode == 37) {
      $('.pacman')
        .animate({
          left: '0'
        }, 'slow', 'linear')
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
        });
    }

    if (x.which == 38 || x.keyCode == 38) {
      $('.pacman')
        .animate({
          top: '0'
        }, 'slow', 'linear')
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(270deg)'
        });
    }


  }).keyup(function() {
    $('.pacman').stop();
  });
});
```

```css
.pacman {
  position: absolute;
}
.cenario {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="cenario">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWuBaJWq9UP_ILy5Tgz5-5Z6dMm8f7URRSh8Pr2pMU0LZfvPEG" class="pacman" />
</div>
```

Obs.: Aconselho deixar o [`easing` da animação em *linear*](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você precisa definir no javascript os limites que o boneca poderá se movimentar. Nesse caso será o `width` e o `height`.

Antes de chamar o `.animate()` você precisa fazer a checagem se o `top` e o   `left` do boneco estão dentro dos limites.

Para saber o `left` e o `top` você pode usar `.offset()` que irá retornar as duas propriedades do elemento.

### Exemplo

```js
var limits = {
    left: 500,
    top: 500
};

$(document).keydown(function(x){
    if(x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39){
        var offset = $('.pacman').offset();

        if (offset.left > limits.left) {
            return false;
        }

        $('.pacman')
            .animate({left: '1180px'}, 'slow')
            .css({ transform : 'rotate(360deg)'});               
    }
});
```

Esse é um exemplo bem rústico, mas é possível ter uma base do que você precisa.